# Why tensorflow does not use flatbuffers by default

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers, flatbuffers

I can see that TensorFlow Lite is using flatbuffers by default and documentation page notes that in fact it's more efficient.

Why isn't TensorFlow using it by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because the team didn't know of its existence when they started it. FlatBuffers is a relatively new technology, whereas Protocol Buffers has been in use at Google almost since the start, and is used for everything by default.

Comment: I don't think so, Flatbuffers Initial release: June 17, 2014,
TensorFlow Initial release date: November 9, 2015. I think it is more efficient in some cases but I want to know when and why.

Comment: and Protocol Buffers were released in 2008. Irregardless of hte reason this is a question for the TensorFlow creators; you will probably get a better answer asking them directly.

Comment: @ŁukaszKurowski Just because it was released in 2014 doesn't mean it was instantly known to everyone at Google, or accepted as a viable technology. The initial release was targeted at games, it took quite a while for teams internally to start taking it seriously (and it still has an uphill battle against the "network effects" of Protobuf). And who knows how many years before 2015 TensorFlow was architected. But hey, don't believe me, I only created FlatBuffers at Google ;)

Comment: @DarrenForsythe Protobuf was used at Google for many years before its first public release, whereas FlatBuffers was created to be open source from the start.

Comment: @Aardappel could you please provide more information, do you think they would use it now if it weren't for backwards compatibility? Or is protocol buffers better for graphs?

Comment: @DarrenForsythe I don't want to ask them directly because they told me in the past to ask such questions here.

Comment: @ŁukaszKurowski Rewriting a large system to use a different serialization system is a crazy amount of work. Too much work. But sorry, I have no idea on how they decided on anything.
Protobuf doesn't support any kind of graphs directly (though you can emulate them with arrays), FlatBuffers supports DAGs directly.

Comment: @Aardappel very interesting! you are right about rewriting but I'm wondering especially because they integrated it into TFLite, maybe in the future.